# Demonstration with Itô's lemma

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-differential-equations

This is my first question here, and I'm asking because I start to have doubts about whether the exercise is right or there are missing elements, and I wanted to ask before going to my professor. Do excuse me it it's been posted before, I've been looking for it for three days but maybe I didn't use the right terms.
I have to solve the following exercise:
Using Itô's lemma, demonstrate that if $f:(0, +\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is a function with a continuous derivative, then:
$$\int^t_0 h_s dW_s = h_tW_t - \int^t_0 h_s' W_s ds$$
I understand the first term, $h_tW_t$ as $F_{W_t}$ in the usual Itô's lemma,
$$\int^t_0 f_{W_t} dW_t = F_{W_t} - \frac 12 \int^t_0 f_{W_s}'ds,$$
but I can't see how
$$\int^t_0 h_s' W_s ds = \frac 12 \int^t_0 f_{W_s}'ds$$
I have also doubts about wrt what is $h'$ derived.
I'm also not fully sure how is $F_t$ $h_tW_t$ ie, why does $h_s$ go to $h_t$ if it's not integrated wrt $s$.
I hope my LaTeX is going to come through as code, I'm sorry if it doesn't.
Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: I'll use $W(t)$ notation here instead of $W_t$.

Observe that the given statement is equivalent to the following differential form:
$$
{\rm d}(h(t) W(t)) = h(t) {\rm d} W(t) +  h'(t)W(t) {\rm d}t.
$$
Your choice of $F$ to apply Itô's lemma is correct: it is $F(t, W(t))$, where $F(t, x) = h(t)\cdot x$.
There is a special case of the lemma for transformations of Wiener process:
$$
{\rm d} F(t, W(t)) = F'_t(t, W(t)) {\rm d} t + F'_x(t,W(t)) {\rm d}W(t) + \frac{1}{2}F''_{xx}(t, W(t)) {\rm d}t.
$$
As $F'_t(t,x) = h'(t)\cdot x$, $F'_x(t,x) = h(t)$ and $F''_{xx}(t,x) = 0$, it follows that
$$
{\rm d} F(t, W(t)) = h'(t) W(t) {\rm d}t + h'(t)W(t) {\rm d}t.
$$

Comment: Many thanks @Yalikesifulei, that was a very useful answer. I've been using the simple Itô's formula, rather than the space and time version all this time and I really couldn't figure it out. Your explanation was precise and clear.